# How to resolve warning: You are installing software that contain unsigned content and authenticity and validity of this software can not established

Tags: android, eclipse, installation, eclipse-adt

I am new to Android . I installed Eclipse Kepler version.

I followed this link.

https://sites.google.com/site/barsham/list-of-topics-1/programming/eclipse-android-windows-64

After doing the following step :

6.1. Start Eclipse, then select Help > Install New Software....

6.2  Click Add, in the top-right corner.

6.3  In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location:

https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

I tried both https and http url.

But the same error box popup which contain the warning related to unsigned content and authenticity.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This warning is just telling you it is not signed, you cant resolve it.  Just click `OK` and continue on.

Comment: what can you not resolve about it?  It just says that its a warning, and give you the option of `OK`, `Cancel`, or `Details`.  Is this the [screen](http://img.my.csdn.net/uploads/201207/10/1341905013_6377.png) you can are stuck at?

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. I have latest eclipse. And due to above error, i am not able to create the new application.

Comment: My problem is resolved now by installation of the full package of the Android and Eclipse.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: Yes that was the screen.

Comment: On that screen if you just click `OK` everything will install as planned.  You cannot do anything about that screen because google did not sign the plugin when they released it.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I can now successfully create sample application from Eclipse Kepler and resolved the problem.

I also added the system variable path through the Environment Variable.

path:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk7\bin;

I think, the mail problem is path variable.
:D
thanks

Comment: @ParagKuhikar I would politely ask, if I resolved your problem correctly that you mark the answer as correct so others can see what solved the problem.  Thank you again

Answer (score 7):

The warning is about security, it is good for you to always care about security warnings and understand them.

As I see it, many developers do not care on creating the signature (or may be it is too troubling?), anyway, for open-source plugins I think it is ok to ignore the warning, as long it is a popular (or at least old enough) plugin. In a sense that, other users may have already poked around the code or reported about security problems related to it.

More about it [here](https://nirmalsasidharan.wordpress.com/2010/09/04/signing_eclipse_plugins/).